# Git: branches differ, but no files to merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I work in a feature branch of a git repo. Meanwhile, the `master` branch changed:

```
my_feature$ git diff | wc -l
     388
my_feature$ git diff master | wc -l
     388
my_feature$
```

When I want to launch `mergtool`, I get the following:

```
my_feature$ git mergetool master
No files need merging
my_feature$ git mergetool
No files need merging
my_feature$
```

However, when I do `git merge master`, I recieve the following:

```
my_featurei$ git merge master
Auto-merging some_dir/some_file.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Auto-merging some_dir/some_file.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Why is this happening and now to fix this?

Comment: Does git diff show some_dir/some_file.php? Why not just fix the conflict and move on?

Comment: @michael Yes it does. This how I wanted to solve the conflict: by using kdiff3 to selectively merge the differences between the two versions of the file

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of `git mergetool`. The first line says (emphasis is mine):

> Use git mergetool to run one of several merge utilities to resolve merge conflicts. It is typically run **after** git merge.